# Find next aligned memory address

Tags: c++, bit-manipulation, memory-alignment

From my understanding of [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure_alignment#Computing_padding), I can find the index of the next closest element with correct alignment by the following bitwise operation.

```
Assuming the address of the 1st element has the correct alignment.
Assuming the index_alignment is a power of 2.
new_index = (current_index + index_alignment - 1) & ~(index_alignment - 1).
new_address = address_of_1st_element + new_index
index_alignment is 16 bytes/sizeof(type of element) for SSE.
```

Is it possible to use this directly on an address to find the next closest aligned address from any given address? (is this way quicker?)

I was thinking about the following to do this quickly.

```
new_address = (current_address + alignment - 1) & ~(alignment -1)
alignment here is 16 for SSE.
```

When I implement this, I found the following code can't compile...

Code fixed with Salva and Rotem's suggestions

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdint.h>
#define ALIGNMENT 16
using namespace std;
uint32_t* fix_ptr(uint32_t* ptr){
    return (uint32_t*)(
        (uintptr_t(ptr) + uintptr_t(ALIGNMENT) - 1)
        &~ uintptr_t(ALIGNMENT - 1)
        );
}
void print_ptr (uint32_t* ptr){
    cout << (long long)(void*)ptr << endl;
}

void test(uintptr_t ptr_as_int){
    uint32_t* ptr1 = (uint32_t*) ptr_as_int;
    cout << "Initial address: ";
    print_ptr(ptr1);
    uintptr_t alignment = ALIGNMENT;
    cout << "    alignment: " << alignment << endl;
    cout << "    alignment - 1: " << (alignment - 1) << endl;
    cout << "    alignment & alignment: " << (alignment & alignment) << endl;

    uint32_t* ptr_fixed = fix_ptr(ptr1);
    cout << "    fixed address: ";
    print_ptr(ptr_fixed);
}
int main(void){
    test(1000);
    test(16);
}
```

Output (compiled with g++ code.cpp)

```
Initial address: 1000
    alignment: 16
    alignment - 1: 15
    alignment & alignment: 16
    fixed address: 1008
Initial address: 16
    alignment: 16
    alignment - 1: 15
    alignment & alignment: 16
    fixed address: 16
```

1000 becomes 1008 and 16 becomes 16 as expected. Probably ok for my current use. Don't know if there are faster ways.

Thanks.

Comment: The fix is simple - do not convert your numbers to pointers, first do all arithmetics and then convert result to a pointer.

Comment: ah. thanks. let me try that and then benchmark it.

Comment: You can do it as follows: `uint32_t* ptr_fixed = (uint32_t*)((uintptr_t)ptr1 + (uintptr_t)(alignment - 1)) & ~((uintptr_t)(alignment - 1));`

Comment: yea. i was thinking about what to convert to, cause for the 64 bit system I work with, the pointer is 64bit, and for 32 bit system, the pointer is (i guess) 32bit. thanks

Comment: uintptr_t applies uint32_t in 32bit code and applies uint64_t in 64bit code.

Comment: This code is a mess! You're passing parameters and returning values, which you never use because you're using global variables instead. And I don't see you calling `fix_ptr` at all.

Comment: yea. was fixing and testing. just updated. sorry about that

Answer (score 3):

The C++ standard library has the [`std::align`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/align) function in the `memory` header to do this since C++11. At least in the [GNU implementation (libstdc++)](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/latest-doxygen/a00329_source.html#l00062) `std::align` does pretty much the same bit-manipulation as OP:

> `const auto __aligned = (__intptr - 1u + __align) & -__align;`

The only difference apart from the position of the first `-1` is that instead of `~(__align - 1)` it uses `-__align` as both are equivalent.

`std::align` also takes a `size` and a `space` argument and checks if after proper alignment the given type still fits into the given buffer/allocation `space`, as well as subtracting the bytes used for alignment from the `space` argument (a reference).

The following is a version without these checks and the additional arguments that were only needed for the checks.

```cpp
#include <cstddef>
#include <cstdint>

inline void *align(std::size_t alignment, void *ptr) noexcept {
    const auto intptr = reinterpret_cast<std::uintptr_t>(ptr);
    const auto aligned = (intptr - 1u + alignment) & -alignment;
    return reinterpret_cast<void *>(aligned);
}
```